# Ruby on Rails: Dynamic function name, based on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

How can I create a **dynamic** function name in rails using the data in the **database**? I don't know if this is even possible.

**here is a sample of my goal**

> ```
> class PageController < ApplicationController
>   def (PageModel.find(1)) #def stay
>    #codes here            #codes here
>   end                     #end
> end
> ```

I know the syntax is wrong. please help, thanks

**Update**

this function will only be called via routes, and in my routes I have this line

> match "/:action", :controller => "page", :via => "get"

the function will look like this if it is manually generated

> ```
> def stay
>  #some query
>  render 'stay_page', :layout => 'stay_page_layout'
> end
>
> def pleasure 
>  #some query
>  render 'pleasure _page', :layout => 'pleasure _page_layout'
> end
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure what your desired method name would be. What would you expect `(PageModel.find(1))` to be replaced with?

Comment: Also, I enjoy answering strange ruby questions, so I will help if I can, but you should know that there is definitely a faster, more clear solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve here than dynamically creating controller methods.

Comment: hi thank you so much. I'm expecting to have names like stay, eat and drink, pleasure etc.

Comment: What is your Controller action supposed to do in terms of CRUD?

Comment: You didn't answer Alex.Bullard's question. What will the generated method names look like? What do your routes look? Or will the methods be called in some other way rather than via routes?

Comment: actually I have a dynamic route. Whenever the user type something in the URL I want to check if it has a corresponding function(based on database) in the PageController if it does then I want to display something, else I want to navigate to the 404 page.

Comment: @TripleAMAC It sounds like you are trying to do database-backed static pages, storing page names in DB and page files in `app/views/page`. That would explain the need for corresponding methods.

Comment: @Jesper. I had updated my question with regards to your comment.

Comment: @Alex.Bullard . I had updated my question with regards to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `PageModel` have `page_id` and `page_name`, your url get `page_id` as an parameter, and will render with `page_name`.

code for controller:

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def dynamic_action
    page_name = PageModel.find(params[:page_id]).page_name
    render "#{page_name}_page", :layout => "#{page_name}_page_layout"
  end             
end
```

route:

```
match '/:page_id' => 'page#dynamic_action'
```

Comment: hi @Jaugar Chang, Your answere is concept of what I want to happen. but it gives me this error "Missing :controller key on routes definition". this is what my routes looks like `match ':home(/:action)(.:format)'`

Comment: I updated my answer according to your update. `method_missing` is not recommended using in controller.

Answer (score 0):

In `routes.rb`:

```
# Either this...
get "pages/:page", to: "pages#page"

# Or this, but make sure this is the last route in the file
get "/:page", to: "pages#page"
```

Your controller:

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def page
    @page = PageModel.find(params[:page])
  end
end
```

If you just need to render different templates depending on the page, you can do this:

```
def page
  @page = PageModel.find(params[:page])
  render @page.name
end
```

If you need custom logic you could do something like this:

```
VALID_PAGES = ["contact_us"]

def page
  @page = PageModel.find(params[:page])
  execute(@page.name)
end

def execute(name)
  if VALID_PAGES.include?(name)
    send(name)
  end
end

def contact_us
  # do stuff
end
```